# How to store all unread notification in android?

Tags: android

Hi,

I am new in android and i have used notification with GCM, But problem is that when i send more then one notification one by one then only last one is available when i scroll down the status bar. I want to show all unread notification when i scroll down the status bar.
My code is below.

```
 private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    System.out.println("generateNotification()   :  "+message);
    NotificationMessageModel.msg=message;
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

}
```

Please help someone
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

The 0 argument corresponds to the notification ID. Give it a different ID for each notification you send. Documentation states:

> public void notify (int id, Notification notification) Added in API
>   level 1
>
> Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification
>   with the same id has already been posted by your application and has
>   not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.
>   Parameters id     An identifier for this notification unique within your
>   application. notification     A Notification object describing what to
>   show the user. Must not be null.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick T, Its working. But still i have problem that how to get id which i set to particular msg for ex.  notificationManager.notify(NotificationMessageModel.unreadNotification, notification);   
        NotificationMessageModel.unreadNotification++;                when i click on the pending notification.

Comment: Hi, I solve this problem. but if i add unique id to notify(id,msg) method then it is showing number of icon depends on the id. For ex. if i send 3 msg then on the status bar it is showing 3 icon. I want show only one icon with number of count.

Comment: This page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating deals with having one notification icon for several messages.